# Calculate length of arc of circle with bigger radius

Tags: geometry, circles

I have the length of an arc of a circle

```
arc1 = 264cm
arc2 = 418cm
arc3 = 413cm
arc4 = 167cm
arc5 = 75cm
arc6 = 76.5cm
arc7 = 158.5cm
```

[image: arc of a circle]

The lenghts are with a radius of 250cm.
I want to know how long these arcs become, when I expand the radius to 260cm.

What is the forumla to calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the radius of the circle be $r$. Let an arc make angle $\theta$ (in radians) at the centre. Then, the length of the arc is
$$l=r\theta$$
Here, you know $r$ and you know $l$. So, use that to find $\theta$. Then, take the same $\theta$, take your new radius, and use that to calculate the new $l$.

In other words, since $\theta$ is constant under "expansion of the circle", we must have
$$\frac{l_1}{r_1}=\frac{l_2}{r_2}$$
So,
$$l_2=\frac{l_1r_2}{r_1}$$
where $l_1$ and $r_1$ are the initial length of the arc and the radius respectively, and $l_2$ and $r_2$ are the final length of the arc and the radius respectively.

Comment: Can I simply divide `l/r` and the result are in `radians` or do I have to transform the result into `radians`?

Comment: @Stophface Just check the edit once. I think, that answers your question. If not, feel free to ask again.